# Click to button flip function not working while same code for another section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have card section with two button and description first one add image that is working fine description section also working fine, another button add video when I click on it then the card flip and some info behind the card, now the issue is when I replicate the same code for another section then the first section flip function is working that time another section flip function not working mean at the same time only one flip function is working.

[image]

[image]

```js
<script>
 // Init Simple Cropper
$('.cropme').simpleCropper();

$('#portrait').hide();
$('.switch').click(function (){
    $(this).text("Switch to "+($('#portrait').is(":visible") ? "Portrait" : "Landscape"));
  $('#portrait').toggle();
  $('#landscape').toggle();
});
</script>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

  document.getElementById('flip-card-btn-turn-to-back').style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('flip-card-btn-turn-to-front').style.visibility = 'visible';

  document.getElementById('flip-card-btn-turn-to-back').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('flip-card').classList.toggle('do-flip');
  };

  document.getElementById('flip-card-btn-turn-to-front').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('flip-card').classList.toggle('do-flip');
  };

});
</script>
```

```css
.flip-card-3D-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  -o-perspective: 900px;
  -webkit-perspective: 900px;
  -ms-perspective: 900px;
  perspective: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#flip-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.do-flip {
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
#flip-card-btn-turn-to-back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  right: 29%;
  width: 145px;
  height: 46px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #000;
}
#flip-card-btn-turn-to-front {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 2%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: .7em;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #00666a;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#flip-card .flip-card-front, #flip-card .flip-card-back{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}
#flip-card .flip-card-front {
    background: #1fa5ad;
}
#flip-card .flip-card-back {
    background: #00666a;
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    right: 0%;
}
#flip-card .flip-card-front p, #flip-card .flip-card-back p {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left:8%;
  font-size:14px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -167px;
  padding: 20px!important;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
#flip-card .flip-card-front p, #flip-card .flip-card-back p a{
  color: #ffc20e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="flip-card">
                 <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <div class="cropme" id="landscape1" style="width: 350px; height: 400px;"></div>
                   <button id="flip-card-btn-turn-to-back">Add Video</button>
                    <textarea name="form_message" class="form-control required border-r-none ht-gallery-new" rows="5" placeholder="Add Description" aria-required="true"></textarea>
                  </div>
                 <div class="flip-card-back"><div class="inner">
                   <div class="description">
                      <p><strong>Note:</strong> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Click</a> here to see how to find embedded video url</p>
                        <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Paste Embedded Video Url Here" name="gmap" class="form-control allow_only_alphabet space video-url-new">
                        <textarea name="form_message" class="form-control required border-r-none add-des-new" rows="5" placeholder="Add Description" aria-required="true"></textarea>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                <img src="images/return-btn.png" id="flip-card-btn-turn-to-front" class="return-btn-bg"></div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Is the other section on the same page? Or, more specifically, do you have 2 div tags with the ID `#flip-card` on the same page?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and given your prompt time much appreciated! Yes the other section on same page yes 2 div tags with the #flip-card id on same page...what I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 unique elements (your flip cards) that are sharing the same ID.
You're best off refactoring this to use classes instead of ids.

Rather than take on all your code, I mocked up a quick example. Notice how I don't use ID tags and notice how I do the javascript. When you get rid of your id tags, you'll need to adjust your css (.flip-card not #flip-card etc) and your javascript. Try and use this example to refactor your code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.flip-button').forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.target.closest('.flip-card').classList.toggle('do-flip');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.flip-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.do-flip {
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='flip-card'>
  Card 1<br>
  <button class='flip-button'>&lt;</button> <button class='flip-button'>&gt;</button>
</div>
<div style='height:100px;'></div>
<div class='flip-card'>
  Card 2<br>
  <button class='flip-button'>&lt;</button> <button class='flip-button'>&gt;</button>
</div>
```